# overriding a swift function

Tags: swift, overriding

following is a copy from my playground (Xcode 7.3.1):

```
class A {}
class B : A {}

class C1
{
    func z ( a: A ) -> C1 { return C1 () }
    func z ( a: B ) -> C1 { return C1 () }
}    
class C2 : C1
{
    override func z ( a: A ) -> C2 { return C2 () }
    override func z ( a: B ) -> C2 { return C2 () }
}
class C3 : C1
{
    override func z ( a: A ) -> C3 { return C3 () }
    override func z ( a: B ) -> C3 { return C3 () }
}

class D1
{
    func z ( a: A ) {}
    func z ( a: B ) {}
}
class D2 : D1
{
    override func z ( a: A ) {}
    override func z ( a: B ) {}
}
class D3 : D1
{
    override func z ( a: A ) {}
    override func z ( a: B ) {}
}
```

Classes C2 and C3 override a class C1 function. Classes D2 and D3 override a class D1 function. Classes Dx only differ from classes Cx by the function returns nothing.

Copy and past this code into your playground. You should get an error in class C2 and C3:

```
Playground execution failed: MyPlayground.playground:8:19: error: declaration 'z' cannot override more than one superclass declaration
    override func z ( a: A ) -> C2 { return C2 () }
```

If class B does not inherit from class A then it's ok. Changing class B definition does not affect classes Dx : it's always fine for them.

I do think "something's rotten in the Swift kingdom". Doing the same in Java is not a problem.

Could you explain me what I did wrong ? Many thanks.

Comment: noticed, this only happens if B is subclass of A. you can try posting this to swift source github i believe, if looking for truth :)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to override the same method twice, with a different scenario...

Comment: Many thanks Denis. In fact it's no good to use a programming language - Swift - with no real specifications and still under development: I mean a language and a compiler you can't rely on. I'll try to report the problem to Apple and I'll tell you if I get a fix...